# get user home directory with electron

Tags: node.js, electron

When I run `require('os').homedir()` from an electron (4.0.1) app I get `/`, but if I run it from node directly I get my home directory:

```
node --version
v10.14.1
 node
> require('os').homedir()
'/Users/myusername'
>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Electron has an API for this:

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname

```
const {app} = require('electron');
app.getPath('home');
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution from UI render

```
import { remote } from 'electron'

let userHomePath = remote.app.getPath('home');
```

Comment: remote deprecated